# Can One Worship God as a Wife?

Tags: worship, devi, bhakti, goddess, wife

Mirabai Worshipped God as a Husband. Saints of the Radhavallabha sect Worship God as sakhi or swamini. There are some devotees who Worship God as their mother, and even others who worship God in the bhava of their Son/Daughter. Is it possible to worship God in the bhaava of a wife?

Comment: You can worship your wife as Devī, but not the other way round.

Answer (score 1):

1. **INTRO** : There is no equivalent word for Ḍharmapathni in English. The word wife will not suffice. Many western translators with British backgrounds used terms like ‘Lord‘ to define the term Pathi, so equivalently used the term Pathni as a wife. Pathi doesn’t mean lord or husband, it means abode or resort. So, a Pathi is a resort for Ḍharma for his Pathini, it sounds very complicated, so let’s simplify it. Ḍharma is an act to uplift oneself in consciousness, and this act is in line with the cumulative well-being of the surroundings. So, Ḍharma is not a selfish act but an act towards the well-being of all. In this path of Ḍharma, she will take a resort in him as his companion, that is why she is called Ḍharma:Pathni.

2: **GOAL** : The GoaL is reach the state of Devi Parvati. The title was given to Devi Pārvatī who became one with Śiva, or one-half of Śiva. This aspect (Swarupa) of Śiva and Pārvatī is titled as Ardhanarishwara.

3. **PROCESS TO ACHIEVE THIS GOAL** :As a Ḍharma:pathni, Śrī Lakṣmī understood Śrī Vishnu more than He could understand Himself and hence is called Nityanapayani. She conquered His heart and made it Her abode, She dwells within Him, and He within Her. When a man’s jiva (soul) becomes one with his Pathni then nothing can come between them and separate them.
4. **CONCLUSION** :We human beings are all considered as ‘Pashu’ meaning those in bondage or tied to one’s karma. Meaning, those who are not free from the cycle of life and rebirth. Irrespective of male or female, all have one Pathi, meaning one resort, and that one resort is called ‘Pashupathi‘. Therefore He (īśvara), is the only Pathi and we (irrespective of human gender) are all who have to reach his company. Sanatana Culture neither have GOD or WIFE concept. Its Ishvara and Prakruti. Ishavara is the Saguna aspect of Purusha. and Prakurti is his expression. So all expression whether its Sankhya or Yoga are assigned as Feminine. In the Natya school all expressions are called LAsya. All expression emerge and go back into Purusha. That is why the Feminine aspect of creation is only worshiped as a mother and never as patni, because its we who have to merge and not the other way round. But Why only Patni has to merge into Purusha? Because there are no two entities. Prakriti (of Shakti) is an expression of Purusha (we are included in that expression) and everything (including us) merge back into that Purusha. That is why patni is not a concept of worship.

[SOURCE LINK](https://sanatanadhara.com/dharmapatni/)

Comment: God despite being 'pati' of everyone can still become a son/daughter for a bhakta based on the bhava of the devotee but not a wife if a devotee wants to worship him that way? If that were true, God would simply become limited, for it would entail certain things are outside his competence.

Comment: why only as a wife, would God become limited? I reason I tried to state is that Sanatana Culture neither have GOD or WIFE concept. Its Ishvara and Prakruti. Ishavara is the Saguna aspect of Purusha. and Prakurti is his expression. So all expression whether its Sankhya or Yoga are assigned as Feminine. In the Natya school all expressions are called LAsya. All expression emerge and go back into Purusha. That is why the Feminine aspect of creation is ony worshiped as a mother and never as patni because its we who have to merge and not the other way round.

Comment: That didn't answer the question, rather sidestepped it. The rationale given is that god has no pati so a devotee cannot look upon him as a wife. But God has no parent(Father/mother) either and yet he is still willing to adopt the role as a child of the devotee who worships him in that bhava....then why can't he adopt the role of a wife if a devotee wants to worship him that way?

Comment: Is it possible to worship God in the bhaava of a wife? This was your question. I answer was very clear. All expression emerge and go back into Purusha. So is the expression of Shakti in the form of prakruti. Hence as I said "its we who have to merge and not the other way round. " If you disagree, no further communication or explanation is needed. Thank you

Comment: I meant the questions posed in the comments weren't satisfactorily answered, rather sidestepped. So God can't be worshipped as a wife because he is Purusha? Then forming even other female relations with God such as those of a mother and daughter should also not be possible, for it mean god can only be worshipped with masculine relations such as by considering him  a father, master, husband , lover etc. but not  a mother, daughter or wife.

Comment: Anyways, It's perplexing that God despite supposedly being capable of forming every conceivable human relation with his devotee (including those of a devotee's son or daughter which would entail a great degree of devotional subservience on his part) cannot be a wife. The Default fallout of this is Either God is limited and there are certain things he cannot do, or humans themselves limit God under their human conceptions and don't want him to be something they don't want to.